# Taking remote orders via app

Tags: square-connect

I have small food store.  I'm working on an app that will allow my customers to download the app, keep up with events, etc., but most importantly, order from my app menu ahead of time, take their CC payment ahead of time and I have their order waiting for them when they walk in.  I want the purchase to now show up in my Square system so I can get started on the order and I would like to use Square POS to take and process the order so I don't have to keep up with two POS systems.  This does not seem possible with Square?  Suggestions, idea, help?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that isn't currently possible with any of the available Square APIs. The best you can do is probably to set up a [Square online store](https://squareup.com/online-store) and allow users to make purchases from your site. [Masala Wok](https://squareup.com/store/masalawokcedarpark) is a good example of what this looks like.